# How can I import Memberships without membership start date?

Tags: civimember, import

I want to import membership in update mode and I don't have `start_date` so at the time of import it shows me `start_date` is required field. I have removed `membership_start_date` required field from `/civicrm/CRM/Member/Import/Form/MapField.php` file after that it is giving me error-

> Invalid value for field(s) : Membership Start Date is required to create a memberships.; Start Date" in import_error.csv file

Comment: We have the same problem. Have you found a solution? Because we don't want to export the date into a file just to get the start_date.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you can't edit the CiviCRM files or database  -  or only will do so as a last resort :)

These are existing memberships, so you should be able to export the memberships info with the actual start date, add the start_date to your CSV file and import with the start date.

I'm surprised membership start date is required....I'll ask that question on stack exchange :)